# is this patent is still valid?

Tags: us6067803

Cooling pouch 
US 6067803 A
Is this patent is still valid?
The official website of Frio says it has patented technology but in patent it has given that claims are cancelled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Patent validity is determined on a claim by claim basis. One patent can have some claims that are valid, and some that are not. The last page of the patent notes that the USPTO has re-examined the patent. Basically, someone asked them to look at it again (and paid them to do it). In that reexamination, the USPTO cancelled claims 1-32. Those claims are no longer valid. Claims 33-57 were not examined. They remain valid.